# How to securely share information between clusters in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cluster-computing

I am looking for  a generic way to 'securely' share information between different nodes in an cluster. This information will just be a string however this transfer must happen via SSL.

Performance is not an concern but the information must always be latest.

I have looked at various options -

1. Use ehcache in a clustered mode. But currently it does not allow communication between nodes using SSL.
2. Store the information in the Database and access it. However I don't want to go this route since someone with DB access can change the values and I want to avoid this(Can't explain why).

Is there a solution(preferably free) which will allow me to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I researched this issue and finally decided to use Hazelcast cluster to share information.

From the [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) website -

> Hazelcast will help you when you need to:
>
> - Share data/state among many servers (e.g. web session sharing)
> - Cache your data (distributed cache)
> - Cluster your application Provide secure communication among servers Partition your in-   memory data Distribute workload onto many servers
>   Take advantage of parallel processing
> - Provide fail-safe data management

I followed these steps to setup everything - http://serversidestuff.blogspot.sg/2012/11/sharing-information-across-cluster.html

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to use something like JMS (see [example](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html)). Basic idea is to send messages to the topic, then consumers will watch for a message in this topic and update node's state appropriately.

Comment: Interesting idea. But I would require a separate JMS server for this?

Comment: someMS server is a must, however you may consider using Apache Kafka for that

Comment: You will need a JMS-compatible MOM (Message Oriented Middleware). OpenMQ which comes as a standard extension with Glassfish serves the purpose pretty well. ActiveMQ will also be a good candidate if you don't want to install a full-blown JEE container.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I finally decided to go with Hazelcast.